# Creating an API filter with comment.body_markdown but without comment.body

Tags: bug, api

I have used the filter editor on https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments to create a filter for fetching comments. From the default settings, removed all `badge_count` and `shallow_user`, and for `comment` removed all but `body_markdown`, `comment_id` and `post_id`, so that it becomes:

[image]

This gave me the filter id `!SWJ_BpB*hHK7nr(.5W` and the following URL: (can't link as URL because it contains a `(` which screws things up with markdown)

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/comments?page=1&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow&filter=!SWJ_BpB*hHK7nr(.5W
```

When using this filter to retrieve the recent comments with the URL above, **I do not see any `body_markdown` in the retrieved comments.**

If I edit the filter again, and also add `body` for the comments, I get ***both*** `body` and `body_markdown` in the result.

Conclusion: `body_markdown` cannot be retrieved unless `body` is also included in the filter. This seems like a bug. I am only interested in the markdown, so why do I need to get the body as well to be able to see the markdown?

Comment: Oh, and btw: You might want to look over your different `filter` tags here on Meta.

Comment: Reported on StackApps: [The field body\_markdown is not returned for comments](http://stackapps.com/q/4840)